# Access all mp3 files in phone memory - Android

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to get all mp3 files from internal phone storage. I don't have an external SD Card.I can not access the mp3 any time result is zero???

Here is the code:

```
public ArrayList<File> findSongs(File root) {
    ArrayList<File> al = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    for(File singleFile : files) {
        if (singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()) {
            al.addAll(findSongs(singleFile));
        } else if (singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wav")) {
            al.add(singleFile);
            System.out.println(singleFile.getName());
        }
    }
    return al;
}
```

And call the method like below:

```
songs = findSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

Comment: And where is the question?

Comment: I'm not getting mp3 alltime result wil zero.

Comment: Query the `MediaStore` for `audio/mp3` files. That will be **much** faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
    public void getSongsList() {
    List<String> fullsongpath = new ArrayList<>();
    Uri allsongsuri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(allsongsuri, null, selection, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));

                String songPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                fullsongpath.add(songPath);
                String artistName = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                int artistId = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID));
                String albumName = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                int albumId = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```